# Preload GMAIL to quicken loading time

Tags: gmail

Is there any way of preloading Gmail, so that I can have a shortcut to it on my desktop (Mac) and it goes straight to the inbox (without the giant gmail logo and loading sign), So it's like running in the background and is there a huge downside to this? Maybe it'll slow my computer down?

It's just I really don't like the default email app on the Mac and would rather use a shortcut, but loading can be a little slow, especially when at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [offline Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-offline/ejidjjhkpiempkbhmpbfngldlkglhimk?hl=en).

**Second Option**

Follow [this](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1306849?hl=en) guidelines.

1. Go to settings.
2. Check "Enable offline mail."
3. Choose your settings, such as how many days of messages you want to sync.
4. Click Save changes.
5. bookmark the page and also save shortcut

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1306849?hl=en

Comment: thanks. This helped. It still has the loading animation but it's brief and pretty damn quick and I suspect it might be even quicker when at home (I'm currently at sea).
Didn't think there would be such a simple answer. Thanks for that :D

Comment: Thanks for update. Please accept the answer as it helped you

Comment: I cannot find that option anywhere :(
Really shouldn't be hard to find, lol, but can't see it.

Comment: There is an upward arrow - and a right (v) mark below that upward arrow - on left side of my answer; please click on them. You can click that. That right arrow is for accepting the answer.