# How can I make Gmail new interface simpler and still effective?

Tags: gmail

In both Chrome and Firefox browsers, I have some problems with the current Standard View of Gmail user interface compared to the previous standard view:

1. Fonts are bigger than before. It drastically reduce the number of emails that can fit in a screen. I have to do more scroll up and down.
2. The automatic completion in search box does a little too much, and half of the time automatically complete and start searching without me being able to correct the search words.
3. almost every operation is slower than before.
4. ... (More than I can type at the moment)

Have I not used the new interfaces in a proper way, and how can I change the modes and settings to be more user friendly?

I just need a simple user interface, when all the basic features are present.

The basic HTML version is simple. One feature that it misses and I like is that automatic retreival of new emails.

I haven't used MUA, MTA, MDA, MRA, or email clients  on my Lubuntu 18.04. Will that be a good solution too? ( If yes, can I keep emails on the remote servers, and store as few as possible on local Lubuntu ?)

Comment: Hi Tim, there's a lot going on in your question, and some of the sub-questions are a bit broad and a matter of opinion/preferences.  Could you narrow this down a bit to something that is answerable?  Perhaps even splitting up your bulleted points to separate questions would make this more tractable.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I haven't figured out how to separate them.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can, at least time being, return to previous version of gmail. https://www.nytimes.com/2018/07/13/technology/personaltech/go-back-to-old-gmail.html
2. Using an email client seems to be a very good option for you as it will also allow you offline access and ease your life.

Comment: The ability to go back to the "old" version of Gmail was removed a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: Please use gmail client then. You can try offline gmail as well.

Comment: Please see this answer too https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/121920/199004